# DRUPAL 7 - How can I hide content from non logged in user?

Tags: drupal-7

I want to show a message to any anonymous user who try accessing a page, something on the lines of "login to view page" with a link to log in.

By searching, I am only getting to hide completely a page from anonymous users, but I want the page the title, or the link to the page visible; when users clicks on it, it displays an error message similar to "Please login to view this page."

I want the same for the attachments: Users can see the attached file, but when they try to download it, the error message "Please login to view this page." should be shown.

Comment: Can you please specify where you want this login link to appear, whether in a menu, or  page content or in a view output or are you placing it in theme files?

Comment: i want it in forum attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You can simly edit your theme code where you output the page, for example in node.tpl.php
you can add:

```
global $user;
if($user->uid){
// code for the logged user output the content
}
else{
print '<div class="yourstyle">custom message</div>';
}
```